How to change reference to cells in excel
I have below formula in excel:
=IF(ISRRFEEDLY(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Kelly",Grafik!H1:H70,0),COLUMN(Grafik!H1:H71),4,,"Grafik"))), "RR Feedly", FALSE)
Whenever I drag this formula down, the reference to range changes from H1 to H2 etc. What I want to achieve is to whenever I drag it down, it changes from H1 to I1, J1 etc.
I was messing around with OFFSET function but couldnt make it work.

Please pardon me if I have misunderstood the question.

my_col is the column with values to lookup (such as "Kelly").
grafik is range containing lookup columns.
Adjust the offset grafik_col_offset to match your range.
Enter the following spill formula in the first cell (cells below need to be empty). There's no need to drag down.

=LET(
    my_col, A1:A5,
    grafik, Grafik!A1:H10,
    grafik_col_offset, 0,
    BYROW(
        my_col,
        LAMBDA(cell,
            LET(
                lookup_col, INDEX(grafik, , ROW(cell) + grafik_col_offset),
                lookup_val, XLOOKUP(
                    cell,
                    lookup_col,
                    lookup_col,
                    "not found",
                    0
                ),
                IF(ISRRFEEDLY(lookup_val), "RR Feedly", FALSE)
            )
        )
    )
)

